# MySQL joining 3 tables using UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, union

*This question is a little long so that it would be clear, thanks in advance!*

## Introduction

I currently have 3 tables using a many-to-many relationship. I need to query all 3 tables and combine them into 1 table.

---

## Problem

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM  `login` LEFT JOIN membership ON login.id = membership.login_id UNION SELECT * FROM  `login` RIGHT JOIN membership ON login.id = membership.login_id
```

And it returns:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | group_id |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | Tom  |        6 |
|  2 | John |        8 |
|  3 | Jane |        4 |
+----+------+----------+
```

---

## Question

I need it to also include the `group_name`. This is my desired output:

```
+----+------+----------+------------+
| id | name | group_id | group_name |
+----+------+----------+------------+
|  1 | Tom  |        6 | Red        |
|  2 | John |        8 | Brown      |
|  3 | Jane |        4 | Purple     |
+----+------+----------+------------+
```

---

## Tables

`login` Table

> A list of all users with auto-increment id

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Tom  |
|  2 | John |
|  3 | Jane |
+----+------+
```

---

`group` Table

> A list of all groups with the `group_id` and `group_name`

```
+----------+------------+
| group_id | group_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Green      |
|        2 | Blue       |
|        3 | Yellow     |
|        4 | Purple     |
|        5 | Orange     |
|        6 | Red        |
|        7 | Pink       |
|        8 | Brown      |
+----------+------------+
```

---

`membership` Table

> Stores information on which user belongs to which group

```
+----------+----------+
| login_id | group_id |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        6 |
|        2 |        8 |
|        3 |        4 |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you should make whatever table is referenced in the `FROM` clause "always" present, and then `LEFT JOIN` from there - it's going to make reasoning about your actual data connections much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the `group` table as well and select the required fields from the tables.

```
SELECT l.id,l.name,m.group_id,g.group_name
FROM  `login` l
LEFT JOIN `membership` m ON l.id = m.login_id 
LEFT JOIN `group` g on g.group_id = m.group_id
```

Comment: I think you must  `join group` not `left join`

Comment: it doesn't matter here as you are left joining on to the login table. So,it would only have all login id's from that table.

Answer (score 2):

Try this... :)

```
SELECT 
  `login`.`id`,
  `login`.`name`,
  `group`.`group_id`,
  `group`.`group_name`
FROM
  `membership`
  INNER JOIN `login` ON (`membership`.`login_id` = `login`.`id`)
  INNER JOIN `group` ON (`membership`.`group_id` = `group`.`group_id`)
```